# How do I remove this dimmer light switch cover so I can paint the wall?

Tags: lighting, removal

I have a dimmer [similar to this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0078RYTLE).

[image]

There are no screws visible from the front.  Looking at it from the side there appears to be two face plates stacked on top of each other.  I can fit my screwdriver between the two and between the last one and the wall.  Gentle prying with a screwdriver doesn't seem to work.

How can I remove the cover plate?

Answer (score 4):

There are screws behind the front cover plate that hold the back cover plate to the junction box.  The front plate snaps into place.

[image]

You can see from the diagram that there should be a small indentation and a tab inside of this.  If you push the tab in gently with a flat head screwdriver, then you can just pull the front plate off exposing the screws for the back plate.

Comment: @Sarah, Although it is possible you have a fairly expensive switch like the one you posted a link, it is *most likely* a regular switch with a small upgraded cover. Either way maple_shaft's answer is correct and you should be able to gently pry/snap it off but it's is *likely* about a $5 mistake if it breaks, not hundreds. [Example Link](http://www.lowes.com/pd_239622-539-CW-1B-AL_?productId=3239057) to similar cover. Wanted you to feel confident/comfortable about removing it.